# How to find where my sqlite is leaking in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-debug

When I run the app and do some actions I get,

A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/project/database.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

How I can debug this

Comment: Post your code where you are using the db.

Answer (score 4):

Since GINGERBREAD There is functionality introduced by ANDROID for developers to detect closable leaked objects.

```
private static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = true;

if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .build());
    }
```

Use this code block in your activity where you want to detect leaked closable objects.

I Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` then you have to close the database connection after the processing is complete by -

```
getWritableDatabase().close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some **uncommitted transactions** 
(You should always close the transaction once you started).
Make sure that you close your cursor then the database.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

```
var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null
var cursor: Cursor? = null
try {

   db = getReadWriteDB()
   val query = "Select * From Table"
   cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)

 } catch (e: Exception) {    
   e.printStackTrace()    
 } finally {    
//     First close the cursor
   if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {    
      cursor.close()    
   }
//     second close the database

   if (db != null && db.isOpen) {
       db.close()
//     Release the database reference
       db.releaseReference()
   }
}
```